# Yellow triangle symbol on Dependencies without error when use wildcards in the PackageReference

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I was recently learning about nuget, in the document [Version ranges and wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards), I tried this function:

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.*" />
```

But I noticed that there is a yuellow triangle symbol on Dependencies without error (I could not post the image directly here, since I have no enough reputation.)

[image]

Nuget restore, clean up, restart VS, None of them resolve this issue.

Reproduce steps:

1. Create a .net core class library project.
2. Add the nuget package AutoMapper 6.2.2
3. Edit the project file, change the version from 6.2.2 to 6.*, save it.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Yellow triangle symbol on Dependencies without error when use wildcards in the PackageReference

I could reproduced this issue by your steps. This issue should be related to the way how you add the nuget package.

When you added the nuget package `AutoMapper 6.2.2` to the .NET core 2.0, it will install tons of dependencies:

[image]

Those dependencies info are stored in the file `project.assets.json` in the `obj` folder. When you change the version from `6.2.2` to `6.*`, nuget could not know if those dependencies are still compatible with the version `6.*`. So it gives the yellow triangle but without any error.

To resolve this issue, you could delete the file `project.assets.json` in the `obj` folder, then restore the nuget package.

Hope this helps.