# Why does NuGet complain about System.ValueTuple (4.3.1)?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, .net-core, nuget, valuetuple

I've just created console F# application for dotnet core 2.
VS shows exclamation mark on `System.ValueType (4.3.1)` package.

[image: Complaining NuGet]

I know this [reference is implicit](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3656):

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.*" Condition=" '$(DisableImplicitSystemValueTupleReference)' != 'true' and '$(_FrameworkNeedsValueTupleReference)' == 'true' ">
</PackageReference>
```

But NuGet seems to be not ok with the situation. This might be somehow related to this [bug](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3788), however package manager does not even show `System.ValueTuple` among referenced packages. Though I see the library when publish application as self contained.

[image]

Should I just ignore this or is it indeed an indication of some problem?

Answer (score 1):

There might be conflict between target framework versions and package version.

According [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/4.3.1), `System.ValueTuple 4.3.1` is not available dotnet core 2.0 . So in order to use `System.ValueType` you need to update its Version 4.4.0 or higher.

Comment: But it's strange, because they use floating version `Version="4.*"`

Comment: And yes, if I explicitly reference package, VS is ok with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just ignore this or is it indeed an indication of some problem?

If you are add the explicitly nuget package, then change it with floating version `Version="4.*"`, you can try to delete the file `project.assets.json` in the `obj` folder, then restore the nuget package.

That because the dependencies of this package info are stored in the file `project.assets.json` in the `obj` folder. When you change the version from 4.x.x to 4.*, nuget could not know if those dependencies are still compatible with the version 4.*. So Visual Studio may gives the yellow triangle but without any error.

You can check the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473056/yellow-triangle-symbol-on-dependencies-without-error-when-use-wildcards-in-the-p).